# How to quit GRUB minimal BASH-like mode and go back to menu?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I hid GRUB on boot so that I can press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to show the menu only when I need it. However, pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> too many times will take me to the GRUB prompt and it's hard to press exactly once during the boot.

How can I exit prompt and back to the GRUB menu? I have tried to use `exit` and `normal` commands but they didn't help. Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> only produces a new line of `grub>`.

Here's my GRUB configuration

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"
#GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Kubuntu"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

**UPDATE**

Actually I noticed that even I don't hide the menu on boot, pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> when the menu is shown will take you to the minimal bash-like mode.

Comment: IIRC press and hold shift or some other key show the hidden Grub menu

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I tried lots of keys but no luck :(

Answer (score 3):

To strictly answer your question, other methods have successfully worked for me, apart from <kbd>ESC</kbd>:

- `exit` command
- `normal` (this caused every entry in GRUB menu to appear twice)

However, my approach would be to use a GRUB script that allows you to use other key to enter the menu, like [grub-holdshift](https://github.com/hobarrera/grub-holdshift/), which lets you use <kbd>Shift</kbd> instead.